# Prepositions with "been"

Tags: grammar

Miss Brown came to this school in 2007. Now using a verb "live" we have to put the same sentence in the present perfect tense. examples:

Miss Brown has been at this school  since 2007, or
   Miss Brown has been in this school since 2007.

Which preposition is correct? I know that when the pupil is at school, it means he or she is there at the moment, and to be "in school" means to study there. What about teachers? And another question: Where can I find the grammar rules about prepositions with a word "been"? Thanks

Comment: There's no need for thanks.  You can delete the comment.  If my answer is helpful you can accept or upvote it. If it is not helpful you can downvote.

Answer (score 2):

The word "be" (or been) is such a base verb that probably every preposition is used with it.

In this sense you may use "in" or "at",  I prefer "at", since "in" sounds as if she has been physically on the school grounds since 2007.

But better would be to use the right verb:

> Miss Brown has been teaching at this school since 2007.

Comment: James K. The sentence "Miss Brown has been teaching at the school" is the present perfect continuous- not the present perfect simple, don't you agree? This sentence  given by me is from the grammar book for children, and they don't know the present perfect continuous tense yet

Comment: "Miss Brown has taught ..." means the same. You can use either.